# display an image I receive as a response from a web service in android

Tags: java, android

I receive an image as a response from a web service and then need to display it in an image view , how to do that?

Comment: A little bit less information you provide. In which format is it coming? Do you already have some code?

Comment: If it comes due example a jpeg in base64 encoding. Then you have to decode the base64 string to byte array and give that to a bitmap instance.

Comment: I don't know the format, haven't tried anything yet, but the response is of Object type so I'll need to cast it to Bitmap

Comment: When your knowledge about web services, transportation is so less. Pls start first reading done guides. We are not here to write your apps.

Comment: No you can't cast to bitmap. When you place a jpeg as byte array in your webservice response normally it is transported as base64 string. On client side you have to go they way reverse and thats it

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use Google Volley librairy for HTTP request.

See the doc here : http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Some code for downloading Image :

```
ImageRequest ir = new ImageRequest(url, new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Bitmap response) {
         yourImageView.setImageBitmap(response);

    }
}, 0, 0, null, null);

RequestQueue rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
rq.add(ir);
```